# Remove all elements with no children from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, recursion, underscore.js

I get the data from the server in the form of `flat tree`. Then I transfer data `JsTree` library that builds a tree to me.
Before transmitting data `JsTree` I filter the data and remove the empty elements of type `folder` that do not have children.

Here are some code I got:

```
dataFilter: function (jsonString) {
  function getItemList(item, list) {
    if (item === null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (item.parent === "#" && item.type !== "folder") {
      return item;
    } else {
      if (item.type === "folder") {
        var itemFolder = _.findWhere(list, { parent: item.id });
        if (itemFolder) {
          return item;
        }
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    }
    return null;
  };
  function removeEmptyFolder(list) {
    console.log(list);
    var treeListTemp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      treeListTemp.push(getItemList(list[i], list));
    }
    var treeList = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < treeListTemp.length; j++) {
      var k = getItemList(treeListTemp[j], treeListTemp);
      if (k === null) {
        removeEmptyFolder(_.filter(treeListTemp,
                                   function(item) {
          return item !== null;
        }));
      } else {
        treeList.push(k);
      }
    }
    //console.log(treeList);
    return treeList;
  };
  return JSON.stringify(_.filter(removeEmptyFolder(JSON.parse(jsonString)),
                                 function (item) {
    return item !== null;
  }));
}
```

Here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/nkqgot2a/11/

This code works almost right. But if the last element contains a child, it is not then removed from the list. Element "folder 9" should not appear in the list after the data filtering.

Please tell me how to fix my function so that it deletes all empty folders?

As yet it seems to me that the recursion is caused by an excessive amount of time.

Comment: `"folder 9"` ___does___ have children. `"folder 12"`'s parent is `"38"`, which is `"folder 9"`. It's not empty, so it's not removed.

Comment: @Cerbrus After the first function call `removeEmptyFolder` removes the element `"folder 11"`. After the second call functions through recursion occurs `"folder 12"` element removal. When the function is called for the third time the item `"folder 9"` has not contain children.

Comment: Because `folder 9` is a folder and has parent `#` and according to your condition `if (item.parent === "#" && item.type !== "folder") {
      return item;
    }` its returning item. problem is happening to only those folder which are at the root and are emply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check i have made many changes in it

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "15",
    "parent": "#",
    "title": "folder 1",
    "type": "folder"
}, {
    "id": "16",
    "parent": "15",
    "title": "file 2",
    "type": "file"
}, {
    "id": "21",
    "parent": "25",
    "title": "file 6",
    "type": "file"
}, {
    "id": "25",
    "parent": "15",
    "title": "folder 10",
    "type": "folder"
}, {
    "id": "33",
    "parent": "#",
    "title": "folder 3",
    "type": "folder"
}, {
    "id": "34",
    "parent": "33",
    "title": "folder 4",
    "type": "folder"
}, {
    "id": "35",
    "parent": "25",
    "title": "file 5",
    "type": "file"
}, {
    "id": "36",
    "parent": "#",
    "title": "file 7",
    "type": "file"
}, {
    "id": "37",
    "parent": "#",
    "title": "folder 8",
    "type": "folder"
}, {
    "id": "38",
    "parent": "#",
    "title": "folder 9",
    "type": "folder"
}, {
    "id": "39",
    "parent": "40",
    "title": "folder 11",
    "type": "folder"
}, {
    "id": "40",
    "parent": "38",
    "title": "folder 12",
    "type": "folder"
}];

function dataFilter(jsonString) {
    function getItemList(item, list) {
        if (item) {
            if (item.type === "folder") {
                var itemFolder = _.findWhere(list, {
                    parent: item.id
                });
                if (itemFolder) {
                    return item;
                }
            } else {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    };

    function removeEmptyFolder(list) {
        var tempItem = null;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            tempItem = getItemList(list[i], list);
            if (tempItem == null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (tempItem == null) {
            if (_.size(list) > 0) {
                list.splice(i, 1);
                removeEmptyFolder(list);
            }
        }
        return list;
    };
    return removeEmptyFolder(jsonString);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    var $beforelist = $('#before_json');
    $.each(data, function() {
        $('<li>' + this.title + '</li>').appendTo($beforelist);
    });
    var $afterlist = $('#after_json');
    $.each(dataFilter(data), function() {
        $('<li>' + this.title + '</li>').appendTo($afterlist);
    });
});
```

```html
<pre id="before_json"></pre>
<p>After:</p>
<pre id="after_json"></pre>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```